# Angular 2 call method of one child from many

Tags: typescript, angular

I have multiple child components generation via `ngFor`. I have one control panel where I want to do some actions with only one `Component` from all multiple components. I want to trigger come method of one component (it's can be absolutely different component an different cases).

I don't know how I can do this. Because `ViewChild` works only for one component. But I have multiple count of this component.

How I can do this? Thanks a lot for any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@ViewChildren`:

```
@ViewChildren('div')
divs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.divs.toArray().forEach((div) => {
  ...
  }
}
```

More details here http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/

If you want more detailed example please provide your code in a [**plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/)

Comment: Thanks Andrei! You helped me a lot. It's very useful information for me.